# Select day range from a time series

Tags: r

I have a time series object that goes from october to februrary. Below I show you some of the values of it.

```
1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5
1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9
1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8
1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4
1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3
1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8
1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8
```

Within this range, I would like to select the interval from 10:00 hh to 15:00 hh of every day and store it into a variable called "midday" values.
Thanks!

Comment: Wait. Is the data you are showing us from a single column, or is that in 3 columns, data, then hours then value?

Comment: The data is xts object with only one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an xts object. This solution is if you had your data in a dataframe first I would do it like this, using `strptime` to extract the hours from the hours character vector and then do some logical subsetting

```
df <- read.table( text = "1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5
1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9
1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8
1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4
1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3
1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8
1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8
")
colnames(df) <- c( "Day" , "Hour" , "Value" )

hours <- strptime( df$Hour , format = "%H:%M:%S")$hour
df$Midday <- hours >= 10 & hours <= 15
df

          Day     Hour Value Midday
1  1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5  FALSE
2  1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9  FALSE
3  1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8  FALSE
4  1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4  FALSE
5  1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3  FALSE
6  1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8  FALSE
7  1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6   TRUE
8  1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5   TRUE
9  1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5   TRUE
10 1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8   TRUE
```

Using xts as @geektrader suggests is probably better for your needs as it is built for timeseries analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xts` for timeseries analysis. `xts` provides handy ways of subsetting timeseries data. For. eg.

```
txt <- '1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5
1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9
1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8
1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4
1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3
1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8
1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8'

DF <- read.table(text = txt, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

xts(DF$V3, as.POSIXct(paste(DF$V1, " ", DF$V2)))
##                      [,1]
## 1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5
## 1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9
## 1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8
## 1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4
## 1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3
## 1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8
## 1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
## 1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
## 1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
## 1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8

XTS <- xts(DF$V3, as.POSIXct(paste(DF$V1, " ", DF$V2)))
XTS
##                      [,1]
## 1995-10-13 04:00:00 460.5
## 1995-10-13 05:00:00 549.9
## 1995-10-13 06:00:00 648.8
## 1995-10-13 07:00:00 684.4
## 1995-10-13 08:00:00 652.3
## 1995-10-13 09:00:00 629.8
## 1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
## 1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
## 1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
## 1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8

XTS["T10:00:00/T15:00:00"]
##                      [,1]
## 1995-10-13 10:00:00 582.6
## 1995-10-13 11:00:00 565.5
## 1995-10-13 12:00:00 543.5
## 1995-10-13 13:00:00 542.8
```